# How can I install the bash for windows that comes with Git without installing Git?

Tags: git, cygwin

I need to install the bash shell that comes with Git without the need to install git.

I like to learn the bash outside the scope Git.

I guess the Git Bash somehow related Cygwin, **but it is not the exact Cygwin.**

I understand that Git and the "Mysterious Bash" don't have a tight dependency on each other.

How can I install the bash for windows that comes with Git without installing Git?

Can I install it independently and integrate git to my separate installation?

Comment: a full-fat git install is what, maybe 150MB? Nobody cares about 150MB. What specific, concrete problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: @jthill, I just want to underestand what eactly is the "bash" that comes with Git on windows. I think Git for windows uses a separate project and just aded it to its package.

Comment: all of them package bash, the GNU shell. To a first and even second approximation they're all identical. This isn't a latest-and-greatest thing, it's been refined continuously for over thirty years now, based on something that was fifteen-ish years old when it started. The one that comes with GfW is a plenty good place to start. Pick *any* of them and learn that, if you're not getting into esoterica you could go a lifetime before encountering differences with any other.

Comment: Unix is a toolkit, tools are built to rely on the presence of other tools because you can be presumed to have or easily get them. There's a core set: a shell, sed, awk, the coreutils, la la. The msys project took the near-absolute bare minimum from mingw, a fairly minimal subset of the cygwin project's port of the whole toolkit to windows. It's just how much of it you want, but it's all the same thing: a tool kit.

Comment: You could install Windows Git and then use bash while ignoring git. How does that not solve your problem? The git command is not integrated into bash; it's just another command available for you to run.

Comment: They've been bundled together, probably in part because they probably use the same DLLs. Note that Cygwin apparently uses a slightly different set of DLLs and installing both Cygwin and msys2 apparently leads to some sort of DLL-hell issues (I keep saying "apparently" because I don't actually *use* Windows myself). There are many versions of bash, though, even outside of Windows, as it's been developed and added-on-to over time, so you'll get into version issues in various corners even on Unix / Linux systems.

Comment: Do you want something like that? https://cmder.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The environment that Git for Windows is bundled with is a variant of [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).  It is indeed based off [Cygwin](https://www.cygwin.com/), and you can install it independently if you like, but it does not offer a Git package.  Cygwin is also available, and it *does* offer a Git package.

If your interest is in learning how to use a Unix-like command-line environment, then you are probably better off installing the Windows Subsystem for Linux.  Ubuntu is a common distribution, as is Debian, and those provide a more realistic Unix environment.  You can also install Git using `sudo apt-get install git` if you like.

Comment: I know how to use bash and linux commands on Linux. I just need to solve the mystery of Git Bash on windows. So it is msys2. Thanks!. You said it is a variant of msys2. Does that means Git project customized msys2 and using it?

Comment: Yes.  You can see them at https://github.com/git-for-windows.  I strongly recommend that you not use it except as part of Git for Windows because that's not a supported configuration and the overworked Git for Windows maintainer won't be able to help you.  Use something that is supported instead.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, why would you want to install Git Bash without Git? And then install git separately??

If you just want to use the Linux Bash Shell (or similar), then follow the tutorial below:

[How to Install Linux Bash Shell on Windows 10](https://itsfoss.com/install-bash-on-windows/)

Otherwise I think Git Bash and Git can only be installed together on Windows, unless they have changed the installation process.

Comment: I just need to underestand that "Mysterious Bash" that is packaged with Git for windown. What the project name?

Comment: The link you provided is "Windows Subsystem for Linux". Far from the bash simulator comes with Git for windows.